# Testing AngularJS controller with Jasmine causes error in RubyMine

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, rubymine, karma-jasmine

I try to test my AngularJS controller with Jasmine in RubyMine.

Here is my test

> 'use strict';
>
> describe('MainCtrl', function(){   var scope;
>
> beforeEach(module('myModule'));
>
> beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope) {
>       scope = $rootScope.$new();   }));
>
> it('should define more than 5 awesome things',
>   inject(function($controller) {
>       expect(scope.awesomeThings).toBeUndefined();
>
> ```
> $controller('MainCtrl', {
>   $scope: scope
> });
>
> expect(angular.isArray(scope.awesomeThings)).toBeTruthy();
> expect(scope.awesomeThings.length > 5).toBeTruthy();   })); });
> ```

I use Karma for run this test. For configure RubyMine to run tests I made all as it was written in those tutorials *https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/preparing-to-use-karma-test-runner.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/running-unit-tests-on-karma.html*

Here is my Karma config file

> 'use strict';
>
> module.exports = function(config) {
>
> config.set({
>       autoWatch : false,
>
> ```
> frameworks: ['jasmine'],
>
> browsers : ['PhantomJS'],
>
> plugins : [
>     'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
>     'karma-jasmine'
> ]   }); };
> ```

But I got this error when I tried to run my test

> src/app/main/main.controller.spec.js:3 describe('MainCtrl',
>   function(){ ^ ReferenceError: describe is not defined
>
> ```
> at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/main/main.controller.spec.js:3:1)
> at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
> at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
> at startup (node.js:119:16)
> at node.js:929:3
> ```

How can I fix this? I'd be glad for any help.

Comment: Are you running your test using the Karma runner or the node runner?

Comment: I thought that I used Karma runner but in fact it was node runner. Silly me! But I have a problem now as Karma runner doesn't find my test and I get 'Empty test suite'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using the karma runner. You need to add something like the following to your config:

```
files: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'js/**/*.js',
  '../../specs/*.js'
],
```

with appropriate list of files. You need to include all specs as well as any files you need loaded for your app, such as angular and other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your plugins `'karma-spec-reporter'` and then you should be able to run it - I believe it is failing because it is looking for the spec reporter.

Comment: I've added 'reporter' to my plugins, but unfortunately this trick doesn't work for me.